# MEF to load DLL one by one

Tags: c#, mef

I am trying to use MEF to load a DLL as an when it is needed, however, the information in tutorials I have read hasn't been the most helpful.

[This site](http://www.milkcarton.com/blog/2009/04/04/5+Minute+Tutorial+On+Managed+Extensibility+Framework+MEF.aspx) gives a bit of code (shown below) but doesn't really explain anything.

```
private void LoadPlugins() {
  var catalog = new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
  var container = new CompositionContainer(catalog);
  var batch = new CompositionBatch();
  batch.AddPart(this);
  container.Compose(batch);
}
```

Basically I have an interface with a Run method and I am implementing that interface with several DLLs. What I'm after is to be able to do something like this (pseudo code)

```
bob = LoadDll(dllPath);
bob.Run();
```

Is there a way to specify the type of "bob" or would it be generic? If anyone can help I would really appreciate it!

Comment: How would you know which one to load?  The point of MEF is that you don't know *anything* about the concrete types except their abstract/interface definitions; how would you determine that it was appropriate to load the import from a specific DLL?

Comment: @arootbeer Actually, that is one usage of MEF, but it's perfectly valid if you already know the concrete type you are trying to instantiate.  However, I think the usage in this case might be overkill for what the OP is trying to achieve.  If you need runtime discovery of what types an assembly exposes (or expose your types) then MEF is pefect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

does this article help: [MEF Load Plugins(dlls) from folder not in Executing assembly but another dll.Can you help?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421320/mef-load-pluginsdlls-from-folder-not-in-executing-assembly-but-another-dll-can)
basically, the solution, i think, would be to use AssemblyCatalog to load your assembly.

Answer (score 1):

What you want can be accomplished with MEF, but it's quite advanced. You either need to construct a cached catalog (see sample in our Codeplex site) or use a different metadata reader such as CCI.

Out of the box MEF will load assemblies to reflect on them (looking for mef's attributes).